# grpc-go how to deal cancellation example

Tags: grpc, grpc-go

I am looking at the grpc example, but I don't understand this example. Can someone explain it to me?

the example located: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/examples/features/cancellation/server/main.go#L52

```golang
func (s *server) BidirectionalStreamingEcho(stream pb.Echo_BidirectionalStreamingEchoServer) error {
    for {
        in, err := stream.Recv()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("server: error receiving from stream: %v\n", err)
            if err == io.EOF {
                return nil
            }
            return err
        }
        fmt.Printf("echoing message %q\n", in.Message)
        stream.Send(&pb.EchoResponse{Message: in.Message})
    }
}
```

Can someone explain the process of this execution, how is it called? thx.

Comment: I think that the server does not paid to the cancellation, since the operation is micro. But in real world cases, you should handle cancellation in server too.

Answer (score 1):

the client call the method

```
    stream, err := c.BidirectionalStreamingEcho(ctx)
```

so server will start the call `BidirectionalStreamingEcho`